# What is the best internal data structure to use on a user-defined List (implements List)?

Tags: java

I have been wondering for some time a simple subject. If I implement a interface and lets say in this example that of the List.

In the example below I have implemented the List interface which makes me add all of these methods. If I am using an ArrayList() the ArrayList would have already implemented the code for me and I would not have to worry about how my data is stored in the collection. If I want to make my own user-defined list then I would have to implement the code for all of the method. One of the methods would be the add method().

Would I have to create may own internal data structure. I could create an array list and just push my variable onto the stack but is that really what a person would want to do if they are creating a user-defined List.

private ArrayList lst = new ArrayList(); <-- internal data structure

But is this what a person would want to do or would it be better to use a dynamic array because using the ArrayList in a instance of a user-defined list is somewhat like using the egg before the chicken. An ArrayList() already implements the interface and the code is built so that the user can use.

If I remember correctly from (Object Oriented Programming) OOP this would be what is referred to as Data Encapsulation.

**Question: What is the best internal data structure to use if you are implementing a List interface?**

I am trying to find out when it would be useful to create a new Collection object for use with my own internal data structure. In the class below there is the implements List which is my own test call that will have all of the methods for the List in the new class test. What I was wanting to know is how to write the internal data structure for this new list class.

Class:

```
class test implements List {

    @Override
    public boolean add(Object arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int arg0, Object arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int arg0, Collection arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator listIterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator listIterator(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object remove(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object set(int arg0, Object arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public List subList(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray(Object[] arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Best representation" depends on a lot of information about exactly how you intend to use this and why you're reinventing it at all -- as opposed to using any of the existing implementations, possibly subclassed if you need to add behavior. There's a reason multiple implementations of List _already_ exist in the library, and that's precisely because none of them is ideal for all purposes.

Comment: The answer is: it depends. Delegating to another List implementation is perfectly fine, and is done by several classes in the JDK: Collections.unmodifiableList(), Collections.synchronizedList() for example are simple proxies to another List. It all depends on what your List should do.

Comment: The only reason to implement your own list would be that you have to use specific internal data structure, so I think you are looking from the wrong direction. Also, normally, you would not implement the List interface but rather extend AbstractList. That way, you would only need to implement three methods (size(), get(int), and insert(int, Object).

Comment: I have to agree with @JBNizet. It depends on what sort of behavior you want your list to exhibit.

Comment: I'd suggest to study the source code of the already implemented lists (e.g. `java.util.ArrayList`, `java.util.LinkedList` etc.). One might learn more than expected by reading the sources.

Comment: You can just access the source code? I actually have never seen the actual source code for the ArrayList but that would be extremely help in what I am looking to do. How do you just bring up the source code.

Comment: @DougHauf It ships with [OpenJDK](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/) (if you already use this JDK, there should be a file named `src.zip` in the installation directory) and is also available for browsing online at various places (e.g. [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/)). ArrayList is [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/ArrayList.java?av=f).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no concrete answer to this question. It depends entirely on a number of things that are very specific to the situation at hand, including but not limited to (and in no particular order):

- Performance requirements.
- Interface requirements (beyond that of `List`).
- Code clarity, modularity, and reusability.
- Threading requirements.
- Intended usage (e.g. do you want fast insert/remove/append/access/etc.).
- Available development time.
- Available testing time and extra work required to test your new container.

Also you always have to ask: Is it worth it? Considering the wide array of containers that already ship with the JDK (as well as the abundance of third-party libraries), if you find yourself in a situation where none of these are appropriate you should step back and make sure that you are absolutely positive that you need to implement a new container (e.g. there may be some higher level algorithm changes that would make this unnecessary).

As for inheritance vs. composition/delegation; the basic "[is a/has a](http://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/inheritance-composition-relationship.php)" rule is generally a good starting point (it's not a definitive rule but it is a good guideline to begin with).

In short, you ask "But is this what a person would want to do?" and the answer is "Yes, if you want to do it, no if you do not."

Answer (score 1):

In almost every case it is better to use the built in structures.

If you have a special datatype then just do

```
ArrayList<YourClass> data=new Arraylist<YourClass>();
```

This will in many cases create less headache for you.